# How to turn System::String^ into std::string?

Tags: .net, c++, visual-studio, string, visual-c++

So i work in clr, creating .net dll in visual c++.

I tru such code:

```
 static bool InitFile(System::String^ fileName, System::String^ container)
{
    return enc.InitFile(std::string(fileName), std::string(container));
}
```

having encoder that normaly resives std::string. but here the compiler (visual studio) gives me C2664 error if I strip out arguments from std::string and C2440  which is in general the same. VS tells me that it just can not to convert System::String^ into std::string.

So I am sad... what shall I do to turn System::String^ into std::string?

Update:

Now with your help I have such code

```
#include <msclr\marshal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
using namespace msclr::interop;
namespace NSSTW
{
  public ref class CFEW
  {
 public:
     CFEW() {}

     static System::String^ echo(System::String^ stringToReturn)
    {
        return stringToReturn;  
    }

     static bool InitFile(System::String^ fileName, System::String^ container)
    {   
        std::string sys_fileName = marshal_as<std::string>(fileName);;
        std::string sys_container = marshal_as<std::string>(container);;
        return enc.InitFile(sys_fileName, sys_container);
    }
...
```

but when I try to compile it gives me C4996

error C4996: 'msclr::interop::error_reporting_helper<_To_Type,_From_Type>::marshal_as': This conversion is not supported by the library or the header file needed for this conversion is not included.  Please refer to the documentation on 'How to: Extend the Marshaling Library' for adding your own marshaling method.

what to do?

Comment: You've included `msclr\marshal.h`.  Try `msclr\marshal_cppstd.h`.

Comment: @Chris Schmich: thank you - now it compiles perfectly=)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're using VS2008 or newer, you can do this very simply with the [automatic marshaling added to C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384865.aspx).  For example, you can convert from `System::String^` to `std::string` via [`marshal_as`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384859.aspx):

```
System::String^ clrString = "CLR string";
std::string stdString = marshal_as<std::string>(clrString);
```

This is the same marshaling used for P/Invoke calls.

Comment: I like idea but how to declare marshal_as in my code? where and what shall i write to declare it (to get rid of error C2065) , I use VS2008

Comment: To go from `System::String^` to `std::string`, you need to `#include <marshal_cppstd.h>` where `marshal_as` is declared.

Comment: when I try #include <marshal_cppstd.h>it gives me fatal error C1083... so I edited code and posted it here in Question (I use what they used in MS MSDN example)... can you take a look at it please.

Comment: Sorry, I was slightly off, you need to include `msclr\marshal_cppstd.h`.  Are you still having this issue?  Your code above still says `msclr\marshal.h`.

Answer (score 4):

From the article [How to convert System::String^ to std::string or std::wstring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1b4az623(VS.80).aspx) on MSDN:

```
void MarshalString (String ^ s, string& os) 
{
    using namespace Runtime::InteropServices;
    const char* chars = 
      (const char*)(Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(s)).ToPointer();
    os = chars;
    Marshal::FreeHGlobal(IntPtr((void*)chars));
}
```

Usage:

```
std::string a;
System::String^ yourString = gcnew System::String("Foo");
MarshalString(yourString, a);
std::cout << a << std::endl; // Prints "Foo"
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to include marshal_cppstd.h to convert String^ to std::string.

You don't mention if you're concerned at all about non-ascii characters.
If you need unicode (and if not, why not!?), there is a marshal_as which returns a std::wstring.

If you're using utf8, you'll have to roll your own. You can use a simple loop:

```
System::String^ s = ...;
std::string utf8; 
for each( System::Char c in s )
    // append encoding of c to "utf8";
```

Answer (score 1):

[How to convert from System::String* to Char* in Visual C++](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311259)

Once you have a `char*`, simply pass it to the `std::string` constructor.