# Including <msclr\marshal_cppstd.h>

Tags: string, visual-c++, marshalling

For my current project, I needed to convert from `String^` to `std::string` and vice-versa a lot. I read I could accomplish that by *marshaling* (from what I've read it's a process of conversion between native and managed data types because they are handled differently in the memory).

I read the instructions off of [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3539334/how-to-turn-systemstring-into-stdstring). I put the code in a button event. Since I'm a beginner, I didn't really know which file do I need to include `<msclr\marshal_cppstd.h>` in. After reading pre-made descriptions in each of the files, I included the library in `stdafx.h`, which produced the following errors:

*error C2065: 'marshal_as' : undeclared identifier* 
*error C2275: 'std::string' : illegal use of this type as an expression*

When including it in the main `.cpp` and `stdafx.cpp` files, one of the errors I get is:

*error C2872: 'IServiceProvider' : ambiguous symbol*

even though I included the file before any "using" directive, as advised [here](http://qualapps.blogspot.com/2008/07/using-atlstrh-in-managed-project.html).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It lives in the msclr namespace.  Don't put this in your precompiled header, you need to keep lossy string conversions isolated so you'll minimize the damage.

Comment: Where do I include it then?

Comment: In the .cpp file where you put this string conversion code.  Do try to keep it to just one file, very important when you eventually fix the bugs.  You eventually will.

Comment: My string conversion code is a part of a button event, that is in the **Form1.h file**. I tried including <msclr\marshal_cppstd.h> both before after #pragma once and both times I get error C2872.

Comment: The full declaration for marshal_as is: msclr::interop::marshal_as