# A non-static member reference must be relative to a specific object

Tags: winforms, variables, textbox, c++-cli

I'm trying to get the text in my textbox `tb_key` to write to my `std::string Key` *Variable* **by doing this:**

```cpp
std::string Key = TRIPRECOILWARE::LoginForm::tb_key->Text;
```

I get an error saying :

> A non-static member reference must be relative to a specific
> object

I tried to search but I couldn't find anything really that fixed it for me.

**Minimal Reproducible Example:**

***LoginForm.h***

```cpp
namespace TRIPRECOILWARE {

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;



private: System::Void tb_key_TextChanged(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) 
{
}

}
```

***LoginForm.cpp***

```cpp
std::string Key = TRIPRECOILWARE::LoginForm::tb_key->Text;
```

I'm trying to use this in ***LoginForm.h***

```cpp
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
    
    if (Authenticate(StringToChar(Key), (StringToChar(hwid)))) // Authenticates key & hwid
    {
        this->Hide();
        Software^ soft = gcnew Software();
        soft->Show();
    }
```

> Basically, I want to get *Key* from Textbox called `tb_key` and write
> it to my `Key` variable defined above. Then use that key to
> authenticate and perform `code`

Comment: You mean `String^ sKey = this->tb_key->Text;`? Assuming LoginForm is the current class. But you can also use `MyNameSpace::LoginForm::tb_key->Text` form anyway.

Comment: Using `MyNameSpace::LoginForm::tb_key->Text` gives me the error mentioned.
I'm defining the Variable in my .cpp file not in my .h original Form file.

Comment: Please show a [mre]. Presumably `LoginForm` is a class not an object

Comment: Then you don't have the Instance of LoginForm, so `MyNameSpace::LoginForm` represents a Type, while `tb_key` is an Instance member. You need a reference to the Instance of the Form you have created. Is this the `MyNameSpace.cpp` file?

Comment: I renamed MyNameSpace in the code above which is TRIPRECOILWARE
So LoginForm is the .h and .cpp file.

Comment: Just forget about "Key" entirely and write `Authenticate(StringToChar(tb_key->Text))`

Comment: You seem to be under the impression that a variable definition creates a permanent connection between the new variable (`Key`) and the initializer expression `LoginForm::tb_key->Text`.  But that is not how variable initialization works.  Rather, it evaluates the expression (once) to become a value, copies that value to the variable, and never looks at the initializer again.  The value in the variable never updates unless you do something to update it.

Comment: Did that and Error: No suitable constructor exists to convert from "System::String ^" to "std::basic _string<charm std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>"

Comment: Add to that a confused mix of standard C++ string and .NET System::String types, trying to access a variable before it is declared, order of operations.... you are better off just cutting out the middleman.

Comment: Yeah, that error concerns your confused mix of standard C++ string and .NET System::String.  What is `StringToChar` supposed to do?

Comment: Here is the code for my `StringToChar`
```
char* StringToChar(std::string string) //A function to convert a string to a char
{
 return _strdup(string.c_str());
}
```

Comment: That function is absolutely useless inside of a .NET program.  What argument types does `Authenticate()` expect?  Is it calling `std::free()` on its arguments?

Comment: bool Authenticate(const char *license, const charhwid="")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your real problem is a duplicate of [How to turn System::String^ into std::string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3539334/103167)

Corrected code:

```
#include <msclr\marshal.h>
#include <msclr\marshal_cppstd.h>

using namespace System;
using namespace msclr::interop;

void button1_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e)
{
    std::string Key = marshal_as<std::string>(tb_key->Text);
    if (Authenticate(Key.c_str(), hwid.c_str())) // Authenticates key & hwid
    {
        Hide();
        Software^ soft = gcnew Software();
        soft->Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!
I got this error tho: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error C4996 'msclr::interop::error_reporting_helper<_To_Type,_From_Type,false>::marshal_as': This conversion is not supported by the library or the header file needed for this conversion is not included.  Please refer to the documentation on 'How to: Extend the Marshaling Library' for adding your own marshaling method. TRIPRECOILWARE C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\msclr\marshal.h 216

Comment: @TRAV: Sorry, I had missed one of the two required header files.  The error message was exactly correct "the header file needed for this conversion is not included".  I've added it to my answer now.

Comment: The list of which header file is needed for which conversions can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/overview-of-marshaling-in-cpp?view=msvc-160

Comment: Thank it fixed it!
I'm facing other errors now LNK2028 and LNK 2019
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error LNK2028 unresolved token (0A00050D) "extern "C" bool __cdecl Initialize(char const *)" (?Initialize@@$$J0YA_NPBD@Z) referenced in function "int __clrcall main(cli::array<class System::String ^ >^)" (?main@@$$HYMHP$01AP$AAVString@System@@@Z)

Comment: It's coming from Initialize("245t8rtZneogWSMsfMsvOPW6UK7yw62DADWjqLWX935rDzIp2K1LeWj4oP4EJhDF");

Which expects const char

Comment: That seems completely unrelated to this question.  Make sure you have that `Initialize()` function defined somewhere, or if it is provided by a library make sure you link with the library.  It seems weird that the name is mangled with all the parameter types even when you have used `extern "C"`