# How to save XmlTextReader strings inside a variable or vector in C++/CLI?

Tags: c++, xml, c++-cli, xmlreader, xmltextreader

I am currently working on a project in which I have to receive a XML file and sort one of the elements.

Before actually getting to the sorting part, I have to parse the XML file, so I am using `XmlTextReader`, which is working well. However, I need to save each element's attribute in a variable or in a vector to be able to perform the sort afterwards (my struggle is with trying to store the `reader->Value`).

Here is part of my code, any ideas?

P.S. You can see my struggle in the second `switch` case below, I kept receiving errors on all those attempts.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <tchar.h>

#using <System.Windows.Forms.dll>
#using <mscorlib.dll>

using namespace std;
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Xml;

int main() {

    string myText = "";
    vector<string> entries = { "DeTal" };
    entries.insert(entries.end(), "Fulano");//test purposes

  
    XmlTextReader^ reader = gcnew XmlTextReader("C:\\Users...");

    while (reader->Read())
    {
        switch (reader->NodeType)
        {
        case XmlNodeType::Element: // The node is an element.
            Console::Write("<{0}", reader->ReadToFollowing("TITLE"));

            while (reader->MoveToNextAttribute()) {// Read the attributes.
                Console::Write(" {0}='{1}'", reader->GetAttribute("TITLE"));
            }
            Console::WriteLine(">");
            break;

        case XmlNodeType::Text: //Display the text in each element.
            Console::WriteLine(reader->Value); //reads the actual element content
            //entries.insert(entries.end(), reader->Value);
            //entries.push_back(reader->Value);
            //myText = Console::WriteLine(reader->Value);
            //myText = Console::WriteLine(reader->ReadString());
            //myText = reader->Value;
            break;

        case XmlNodeType::EndElement: //Display the end of the element.
            Console::Write("</{0}", reader->Name);
            Console::WriteLine(">");
            break;
        }
    }
    cout << "\nPress enter to start sort: ";
    Console::ReadLine();
```

Comment: When posting questions, and you say you are struggling, please explain what you are actually struggling with. And when you are getting errors, please show the actual errors.

Comment: Using a `List<String^>^` is an obvious solution.  If you have a hard need for std::string then you'll have to [convert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3539334/how-to-turn-systemstring-into-stdstring).

Comment: @RemyLebeau thank you for the feedback and sorry about that, this was my first post

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`reader->Value` is a .NET `System::String` (a 16bit Unicode string).

You are trying to assign it to, and store it in a `std::vector` of, `std::string` (an 8bit string).

Those two string types are not directly compatible with each other, which is why you are having troubles.

You need to either:

- change your `myText` variable to `System::String`, and your `entries` vector to hold `System::String` elements.
- *convert* the `System::String` data to `std::string`. How to do that is documented on MSDN: [How to: Convert System::String to Standard String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/how-to-convert-system-string-to-standard-string). Also see [How to turn System::String^ into std::string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3539334/) on StackOverflow.